# Changing Color Within Header Element Not Working Correctly

Tags: html, css, header

I'm using Wordpress and I want to display a  element with part of the text within the element to show as a different color. I believe I have the syntax correct and in the Wordpress visual editor it looks fine. But when I preview the page the font with the light blue color looks smaller (basically it lost some of the formatting). I'm wondering what would make this happen.

This is what I have:

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center;">ABOUT <span style="color: #359ed3;">MY BUSINESS</span></h3>
```

Comment: Can you show it on your actual site?

Comment: Looks fine from what you posted here, so odds are that you have other CSS rules being applied. We'll need a [mcve] to see what you're seeing.

Comment: theres probably a span code in your css or parent that is adding to it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try adding `!important;` to it, which makes it mandatory:

```
<h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px !important;">ABOUT <span style="color: #359ed3 !important;">MY BUSINESS</span></h3>
```

Note: You should only use it, if you have exhausted everything else: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/